# Avoid INSERT when the combination of First name and Last already exists - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

newbie and appreciate your help.

So I have the below employee table with emp_id as primary and auto incremental. I would like to avoid users from inserting new record when the combination of **first_name** and **last_name** already exists.

I am connecting the DB to windows from (VB.net), ultimately I would like to display a message saying that the user's first and last name already exists. I could do it progrmaticly by vb code, however i am wondering if I can setup this check at the database level.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `emp_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `gender` char(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id'),
  UNIQUE KEY `employee_id_UNIQUE` (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: side note: `UNIQUE KEY employee_id_UNIQUE (emp_id)` is redundent a `PRIMARY KEY(emp_id)` is already unique so it can be removed

Comment: Thank you @RaymondNijland for pointing this out. I will make sure to remove it.

Comment: unique key on first name and last name - but it's not unusual for many people to have same frist and last names so maybe include dob in key

Comment: I agree, however for the purpose of this application there won't be any duplicate case where the First name and Last name are the same in another record. This is why I want to safeguard the data before insert.

Comment: why use `emp_id` not `id`? we know it is employee id when we use id field of this table

Comment: I suggest not doing that if you work in the giant company, maybe there is peson who has the same name

Comment: @TaurusSilver it is for personal my own company use…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make constraints on sets of columns like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `emp_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `gender` char(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id'),
  UNIQUE KEY `employee_name_UNIQUE` (`first_name`, `last_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

That means if the combination of first_name and last_name already exists in the database, if you try to insert a new row with the same values, it results in a duplicate key error.

You need to write code in your application to handle that error, and then display an appropriately helpful message to the user.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Used this to alter the table: 'ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT `employee_name_UNIQUE` UNIQUE (`first_name`, `last_name`)'